# Can the name-value-pair of a cookie not contain the character =?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am dealing with a third party JavaScript code that sets a cookie through `document.cookie=` but without using the `key=value` format ; instead of doing `document.cookie="mykey=myvalue"` it does `document.cookie="10254/1/19,20,/0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,//20"`.

This leads to issue on my server side code, as Chrome and Firefox send this to my server as a cookie without name and with value "10254/1/19,20,/0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,//20". Safari sends a series of cookies without values and with names "10254/1//0,//-1", "10254/1//0,1,//-1", "10254/1//0,1,2,//-1", etc.

Is it legal to set a cookie without the format `key=value`? I've read https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1.1 and seen `cookie-pair = cookie-name "=" cookie-value` but it is not clear for me whether `=` is mandatory. I think it is, just would like a confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

Answering myself: cookies without `=` should be ignored by the user agent. From http://trac.tools.ietf.org/wg/httpstate/trac/ticket/1

> Per discussion on the mailing list and at IETF77, I've removed nameless cookies from the draft. Cookies without names (either because they lack a "=" or because "=" occurs as the first character of the set-cookie-string") are now ignored by the user agent.

But in practice browsers do send cookies whose `name-value-pair` does not contain `=`. They do not have the same behavior though: for instance if I set a cookie with `document.cookie("foo")`, Safari will send to the server a cookie with name "foo" and a blank value, while Chrome will send a cookie with a blank name a the value "foo".